# Django - decorators restrict "staff"

Tags: python, django

My goal is to restrict the access the the "staff Group" I am trying to do that with the decorators.py but when I do that, it restricts every user I have registered and not only the staff. When I log in with admin it gives me " you are not authorized" that should be only for the "staff" that should see only one template of the platform.

Here the picture also of my admin page.

[image: users]

[image: staff users]

[image: users]
core/decorators.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def allowed_user(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()

            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

            else:
                return HttpResponse(' You are not Authorized!')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

core/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .decorators import allowed_user

# Create your views here.
from quiz.models import Questions
from jobs.models import post_job




@allowed_user(allowed_roles=['Admin, Students'])
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'core/homepage.html')

 @allowed_user(allowed_roles=['Admin, Students'])
def userProfileView(request, username):
    user= get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    jobs = post_job.objects.all()
    categories = Questions.CAT_CHOICES
    scores = []
    for category in categories:
        score = Questions.objects.filter(category=category[0], student= user).count()
        scores.append(score)

    context = {

    'user' : user, 'categories_scores' : zip( categories,scores),
    'jobs': jobs



    }
    return render(request, 'core/user_profile.html' , context)



class UserList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'core/users.html'
```

account/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.forms import FormRegistrazione
from .decorators import allowed_user

# Create your views here.

def registrazioneView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormRegistrazione(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
            User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")


    else:
        form = FormRegistrazione()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/registrazione.html', context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `allowed_roles` are strings, so `group in allowed_roles` will always be false. Especially since `group` is a `QuerySet` of `Group`s, so a collection. That collection can contain zero, one, or more groups.

You can check if the group exists with `request.user.groups.filter(name__in=allowed_roles).exists()`, so the decorator looks like:

```
from functools import wraps

def allowed_user(allowed_roles=()):
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=allowed_roles).exists():
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not Authorized!')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution! I'm having hard times understanding this process since days. If I put this code in decorators, and I leave  @allowed_user(allowed_roles=['Admin, Students']) in my views.py I get that "name 'wraps' is not defined".

Comment: @mattiazm: yes you need to import it, it is a function from the `functools` module.

Comment: ok perfect, so basically I import the functools import wraps and then I leave the @allowed_user(allowed_roles=['admin, students']) on my views.py and should work?

Comment: @mattiazm: yes. But I strongly advice to test this, since it is possible I misunderstood (some parts) of your question :)